# Getting NullPointException with Jersey REST Client on Android

Tags: android, jersey

My code is:

```
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource web_resource = client.resource("http://www.myhostname.com/");
    // String string = web_resource.path("foo").accept("text/xml").get(String.class);
    // Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "jax-rs client string = " + string);
    Num num = web_resource.path("foo").accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE).get(Num.class);
```

The last line causes the problem, and I get a similar problem if I replace it with the 2 commented lines with the difference that I get the exception on a different line of MediaType.java.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  840): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  840):    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.toString(MediaType.java:265)
E/AndroidRuntime(  840):    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientRequest.getHeaderValue(ClientRequest.java:232)
E/AndroidRuntime(  840):    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.writeOutBoundHeaders(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:276)
E/AndroidRuntime(  840):    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:197)
E/AndroidRuntime(  840):    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime(  840):    ... 17 more
```

jersey-client.jar and jersey-core.jar have been added to the package at the top level and have been added to libraries in build path.

AndroidManifest.xml contains:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: i would really like to see the modified code, any updates?

Comment: @Sponge, sorry I am on a different track and it will be weeks before I do anything Android related. I did not use code-control and the code is in several separate directories. I can get to that if you remind me in a week or so but in the meanwhile, consider: (1) android classloader can't read package level annotations which prevents JAXB from initializing; can fix with manual scanning; that was key I remember; (2) the classes and their calls had to be relocated to different packages because javax is restricted; (3) the result was a rather big jar file which might not work for distribution

Comment: i did not investigate the possibility of removing classes from the jar file that were not in use which might have shrunk it and made it totally worthwhile to use jersey.  given this, let me know your level of interest and i'll see if i can dig up the code from the various directories.

Comment: jep I am still interrested in getting the Jersey client to work on Android (and i think there will be more people running into this problem in the future) so it would be great if you could share your solution

Comment: I met this problem last night and the only way I can make my project word is to user Apache HttpClient instead of Jersey Client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a huge exercise. I believe I might be the only person yet who has gotten Jersey+JAXB working on Android. A specific answer won't help because after I got around this NullPointerException I got another exception, and then another.

I had to change source code for Jersey and JAXB in order to make this happen.  And I also had to repackage the jars.

Sorry I know this is a bad quality answer but please comment me if somebody really wants to go down this difficult path in which case I can retrace my steps and help out.

Comment: Why don't you contribute the code back to Jersey? A lot of people would be very happy :)

Comment: I will attempt to do so when I get back on this track of development (I will have to re-understand and identify/briefly-document the correct updates). I am sidetracked on something else for now. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: That is really great necromancer  i am stuck at same point ... can you help me ? by this name i guess you are dota or frozen throne fan

Comment: @AbhijitGujar sorry i am way too busy with a different project. just keep repackaging the jars in a different namespace and work through the exceptions. all i can say is that there will be light at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: @AbhijitGujar no, i don't know dota or frozen throne. there's a stackoverflow badge called necromancer.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with jersey. I switched to [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and everything worked out OK.

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know your solution -- I am looking to stick to the standard before completely giving up and switching to a non-standard library. I realize in Android there may be no other way but I want to be totally sure before switching.

Comment: oh, please upvote the question if you would also be interested in the resolution.

Comment: Why is jersey any more standard than gson ?

Comment: Jersey is part of the Java EE spec? and consequently on track to be part of Java SE?  Or am I wrong?  Or does Gson implement the same JSR and hence a drop-in replacement?  Sorry if I am missing something..

Comment: It's an implementation of JAX-RS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services), but you just need a client to consume the service. If you can get your service to output JSON, you can use GSON inplace of Jersey Client.